# Java Error - Unknown Format Conversion Exception

Tags: java, formatting, printf

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '-'

    at java.util.Formatter.checkText(Formatter.java:2579)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2565)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2501)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
    at IntGrid.printGrid(IntGrid.java:28)
    at IntGrid.main(IntGrid.java:20)
```

So this is the error I'm getting. I'm guessing it has something to do with my formatting for the printf line but I'm not sure how to fix it. Trying to print an integer and have some spaces come after it to make the total width 5 chars.

My code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class IntGrid {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a number of rows:");
    int rows = reader.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter a number of columns:");
    int columns = reader.nextInt();

    printGrid(rows, columns);

}

public static void printGrid(int rows, int columns) {
    int start = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i ++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= columns; j = j + rows) {
            System.out.printf("%-5.d", j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You may want this instead:

```
System.out.printf("%-5d", j);
```

because `.` (decimal point) is used for floats/doubles.